# PR on master "messed" up my test branch, how do I fix it?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I am used to use git.
My normal workflow is:

```
dev --> test --> master
```

I love it and it works great.

Now, in a project I am working on with other remote developers, I have been instructed to include a pull request of someone else's work in our common repository.

I got a PR email, went to github, and after a quick check hit the merge button. Then I went to my local repo, did `git pull origin master`, and the new changes appeared there. All fine.

But here's the catch. I had been initially requested to do a change on some files affected by the PR. I had worked on `dev`, and pushed to `test` - but not `master`.

So naturally, `master` and `test` had differences. I thought I could get them out of the way by simply issuing `git merge master` after `git checkout test`.

To my (initial) surprise, I have now, in `test`, both changes - my colleagues and mine, and `git diff master` from inside `test` shows differences.

I now understand - I would have to had to first dump my obsolete changes.

Having become concerned, and having to update `dev` as well, which has current changes, how do I fix it now? Can I undo the merge on `test` and start from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach for you is to rebase `test` on the new `master`

```
git checkout test
git rebase master -i
```

You can remove your obsolete commit during the rebase.

Comment: Thanks @Igal S., this probably is a good solution. But after seeing the rebase interactive file commits and seeing that I had different commits interspersed, some of which I needed and some not, I got panicked haha. I resorted to manual....

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to do it manually.

After calming down after initial panic, I realized the changes were small and affected just 5 files.

So I went there, copied them from `master` to `/tmp`, checked out `test` and copied them back on.

No differences left between `master`and `test` for the affected directory now. Phew.